# numpy matrix population very slow

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a program to perform numerical calculation with a Hessian matrix. The Hessian matrix is 500 x 500 and I need to populate it hundreds of times over. I am populating it with two for loops each time. My problem is that preventatively slow. Here is my code:

```
#create these outside function
hess = np.empty([500,500])
b = np.empty([500])

def hess_h(x):
    #create these first so they aren't calculated every iteration
    for k in range(500):
        b[k] = (1-np.dot(a[k],x))**2

    for i in range(500):
        for j in range(500):
            if i == j:
                #these are values along diagonal
                hess[i,j] = float(2*(1-x[i])**2 + 4*x[i]**2)/(1-x[i]**2)**2 \
                            - float(a[i,j]*sum(a[i]))/b[i]
            #the matrix is symmetric so only calculate upper triangle
            elif j > i :
                hess[i,j] = -float(a[i,j]*sum(a[i]))/b[i]
            elif i > j:
                hess[i,j] = hess[j,i]
    return hess
```

I calculate that `hess_h(np.zeros(500))` takes 10.2289998531 sec to run. That is too long and I need to figure out another way.

Comment: Take the sum over `a[i]` out of the loop, just like you did for `b`

Answer (score 0):

Look for patterns in your calculation, in particular things that you can calculate over the whole range of `i` and `j`.

I see for example a diagonal where `i==j`

```
hess[i,j] = float(2*(1-x[i])**2 + 4*x[i]**2)/(1-x[i]**2)**2 \
            - float(a[i,j]*sum(a[i]))/b[i]
```

Can you change that to a one time expression, something like:

```
2*(1-x)**2 + 4*x**2)/(1-x**2)**2 - np.diagonal(a)*sum(a)/b
```

The other pieces work with up and lower triangular elements.  There are functions like `np.triu` that give you their indices.

I'm trying to give you tools and though processes for solving this with a few `numpy` vectorized operaitons, instead of iterating over all elements of `i` and `j`.

Looks like

```
 -a[i,j]*sum(a[i])/b[i]
```

is used for every element. I assume `a` is a (500,500) array.  Can you use

```
 -a*a.sum(axis=?)/b
```

`b` can be 'vectorized'

```
 b[k] = (1-np.dot(a[k],x))**2
```

with something like:

```
 (1 - np.dot(a, x))**2
```

or

```
 (1 - np.einsum('kj,ji',a,x))**2
```

test the details on a smaller `a`.